# Simple guestbook made using Java EE 7

Tags: java, jpa, jsf

I'm making my first steps in Java EE. This is a simple guestbook made using Java EE 7 technologies (JSF, CDI, EJB, JPA).

Does the code follows the standard best practices? Is there a possibility for improvement?

[image]

**Guestbook entry entity**

```java
package learning.guestbook2;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM GuestbookEntry g")
public class GuestbookEntry implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8020012557332377340L;
    private String content;
    private String name;
    private OffsetDateTime dateTime;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    public GuestbookEntry() {
        dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Guestbook entry from " + name + ", posted " + dateTime;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

**EJB responsible for business logic**

```java
package learning.guestbook2;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

@Stateless
public class GuestbookEntryEJB {
    @Inject
    protected Logger log;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "GuestbookEntries2")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<GuestbookEntry> findEntries() {
        TypedQuery<GuestbookEntry> query = 
                em.createNamedQuery("findAll", GuestbookEntry.class);
        List<GuestbookEntry> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public void save(GuestbookEntry entry) {
        em.persist(entry);
        em.flush();
        log.info("Guestbook entry saved: " + entry.toString());
    }

    public String getStringDateTime(GuestbookEntry entry) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = entry.getDateTime().toLocalDateTime();
        return localDateTime.format(formatter);
    }
}
```

**Logger producer**

```java
package learning.guestbook2;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerProducer {
    @Produces
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return Logger.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }
}
```

**Controller - CDI bean**

```java
package learning.guestbook2;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class GuestbookEntryController {
    @EJB
    private GuestbookEntryEJB entryEJB;
    private GuestbookEntry entry = new GuestbookEntry();

    public void save() {
        entryEJB.save(entry);
    }

    public List<GuestbookEntry> findEntries() {
        return entryEJB.findEntries();
    }

    public String getStringDateTime() {
        return entryEJB.getStringDateTime(entry);
    }

    public GuestbookEntry getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(GuestbookEntry entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    public GuestbookEntryEJB getEntryEJB() {
        return entryEJB;
    }

    public void setEntryEJB(GuestbookEntryEJB entryEJB) {
        this.entryEJB = entryEJB;
    }
}
```

**View - guestbook.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>#{msg.page_title}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_entry}" styleClass="header"/><br/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_name}&#160;"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{guestbookEntryController.entry.name}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_msg}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:inputTextarea 
            rows="5" cols="100" 
            value="#{guestbookEntryController.entry.content}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:commandButton 
            value="#{msg.submit}" action="#{guestbookEntryController.save()}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.entries}" styleClass="header"/><br/>
        <br/>
        <ui:repeat 
            value="#{guestbookEntryController.findEntries()}" 
            var="value">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.posted} 
                #{guestbookEntryController.getStringDateTime()} 
                #{msg.by} #{value.name}"
                styleClass="guestbookEntryHeader"/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{value.content}" styleClass="guestbookEntry"/>
            <br/><br/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

**css.css**

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE",  Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;  
}

.header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE",  Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0000ff;  
}

.guestbookEntryHeader {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE",  Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777777; 
}

.guestbookEntry {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE",  Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000000; 
}
```

**Configuration files:**

*persistence.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="GuestbookEntries2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/guestbookentries2</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*beans.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

*faces-config.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
                    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>MessagesBundle</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

*web.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.1">
  <display-name>guestbook2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>guestbook.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the UI:

1. While colons at the end of labels are usual in rich client UIs I'd omit them on a web UI. See SE's [profile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/56292/ultranoise) and [profile edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/edit/56292) pages, for instance.
2. Increase the width of the `name` field. What if *[Gloria, Princess of Thurn and Taxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria,_Princess_of_Thurn_and_Taxis)*  visits your guest book? (And hopefully she doesn't want to enter her *full* name then :-)
3. +1 for offering a resizeable text area. I've seen too many web pages where the designer's assumption about the text length to be expected was too small.